# Проблема с удалением большого объема данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc

Есть следующий код

```
var purchases = _purchaseRepository.Query(x => x.CompanyId.Equals(companyToDelete.Id)).Select(x => x.Id);


foreach (var purchase in purchases)
{
    _purchaseRepository.Delete(purchase);
}
```

остальное тело метода 1 в 1 повторяет приведенный кусок кода, отличаются только сущности в выборке.

Время выполнения  куска приведенного в примере - 10 минут.

purchases-коллекция из 7000+   Idшников,
в данном методе таких циклов 20+ в каждом разное кол-во данных, все данные  отобраны  заранее.

Данный метод от начала до конца срабатывает за 30 мин,
SaveChanges вынесено на уровень выше.

Как можно ускорить выполнения данного метода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework реализует паттерн *Единица работы*, который аккумулирует набор изменений и вносит все изменения в рамках одной транзакции.

Из-за этого некоторые сценарии работают медленно.

Решений есть два.

1. Сконструировать SQL-запрос самостоятельно и выполнить его через [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).
2. Использовать готовую библиотеку, например, [BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions).

Также в EF есть метод [`RemoveRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-2.1), но он удаляет сущности, уже загруженные в контекст, поэтому я подозреваю, что он не будет выполняться существенно быстрее.

Comment: А я как раз думаю, что RemoveRange будет работать быстрее.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно. Насколько я понимаю, если он удаляет сущности из контекста, их сначала нужно туда загрузить. Это займёт время. Кроме того, для каждой сущности, видимо, будет своя инструкция `DELETE`, там ведь не queryable-запрос, а сущности. В общем, я сомневаюсь, поэтому рекомендовал заведомо быстрые методы.